# Rails server uses different ruby version than specified by rbenv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

In my rails project, when I try to run the rails server, I get the following error:

`Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.2`

However, when I run `ruby --version` I get:

`ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]`

Also, both the **rbenv global** and **rbenv local** are set to be `2.7.2`

Currently, running `rbenv versions` returns

- system
- *2.7.2 (set by /home/user_name/myProject/my_project/.ruby-version)

Both my **Gemfile.lock** and **.ruby-version** files have ruby 2.7.2 version specified.

Also, when running the server I get the message "the running version of Bundler (2.1.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (2.1.4)", while the bundler's version is `Bundler version 2.1.4` when checked.

I can't figure out why the task is using a completely different ruby and bundler version.

Comment: Have you tried `bundle exec rails s`?

Comment: The error message: `the running version of Bundler....` is unrelated, and not relevant to the problem.

Comment: A likely culprit is that you have a conflict between ruby installations - e.g. you also installed a system `ruby`, or used multiple version managers such as `rvm`.

Comment: I understand that it's unrelated @TomLord. What I'm trying to point out is that using `bundle exec rails s` should avoid the system ruby and use the one specified in the Gemfile.

Comment: @rdalpra You never mentioned `bundle exec` in your question. You just said "when running the server". And that warning could still appear if you have only installed bundler version `2.1.2` against ruby `2.7.2`. To fix that, you'd need to `gem update bundler` but, like I said above, I highly doubt that will make a difference to your core problem here.

Comment: What do `which ruby` and `which bundler` report? And `/usr/bin/ruby --version`? It sounds like you might be running something like `bundle exec rails s`. I'm wondering if it's possible that you're picking up the system `/usr/bin/bundler` executable, because you've never installed bundler for 2.7.2. Also try `which gem` to make sure it's picking up your rbenv `gem` command

Comment: @JayDorsey i do have bundler installed for the specific ruby version.
```which ruby``` => ```/home/sheriff/.rbenv/shims/ruby```,
```which bundle``` => ```/home/sheriff/.rbenv/shims/bundle ```
But somehow,
```which rails``` => ```/usr/local/bin/rails```
I am unsure why shims is not being created for rails. I've tried the following:
```gem install 
rails rbenv rehash 
```

Comment: Running `bundle exec rails <command>` should _probably_ fix your problem (I think). I'm not sure what would create that `/usr/local/bin/rails` file but if you `cat /usr/local/bin/rails` you might get a hint (it might show what installed it). It could be homebrew that installed ruby/rails. Try `/usr/local/bin/gem uninstall rails` and see if that removes that file; that should be relatively safe to uninstall since you're using rbenv now. You can always re-run w/ install to "undo" that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your rails server with bundle too? like:

```
$ bundle exec rails s
```

Because bundle will use gems from your Gemfile, instead of trying to find them globally.

If you are already using with `bundle exec`, what are the returning of:

```
$ which ruby
$ which bundle
```

Comment: ```$ which ruby```
returns ```/home/sheriff/.rbenv/shims/ruby```
. It's Similar for bundle. But

```$ which rails``` 
is returning ```/usr/local/bin/rails```. I am unsure why shims is not being created for rails.
I've tried
```gem install rails
rbenv rehash
```

Comment: linux try to find binaries following the order on your $PATH env var. It sems that you have installed rails globally once, and it was installed on `/usr/local/bin/rails`. Try enforce `rbenv` binaries before the `/usr/local/bin` on your PATH by adding into your `.bashrc` the following lines: `export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH` and `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
gem install bundler:2.1.4
gem update --system
```